# r plotly equivalent ggplot2 to python

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

How to manually set the labels of the points in a plotly?

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
p <- iris %>% 
 ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
 geom_point() +
 labs(
  title = "A graph",
  x = "Sepal Length (cm)",
  y = "Sepal Width (cm)",
  color = "Species of Iris"
) 

ggplotly(p)
```

The axis are correctly labelled, but the data is not.
[image: R output]

---

Here is an example of how it works in Python

https://plotly.com/python/figure-labels/

```py
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_length", y="sepal_width", color="species",
                 labels={
                     "sepal_length": "Sepal Length (cm)",
                     "sepal_width": "Sepal Width (cm)",
                     "species": "Species of Iris"
                 },
                title="Manually Specified Labels")
fig.show()
```

[image: result of popups]

Comment: You might check here: https://plotly.com/r/hover-text-and-formatting/

Comment: None of these examples use ggplotly. They all build their plotly from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using the `text` aesthetic that ggplot doesn't use, but which gets passed along to `plotly`, and `glue::glue` as an alternative to `paste0`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
p <- iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point(aes(text = glue::glue(
    "Species of iris={Species}\n",
    "Sepal Width (cm)={Sepal.Width}"))) +
  # alternative using base paste0:
  #geom_point(aes(text = paste0("Species of iris=", Species, "\n",
  #                             "Sepal Width (cm)=", Sepal.Width))) +
  labs(
    title = "A graph",
    x = "Sepal Length (cm)",
    y = "Sepal Width (cm)",
    color = "Species of Iris"
  ) 

ggplotly(p, tooltip = 'text')
```

Comment: Oh that works! thanks, not the most elegant syntax, but it will do.